# About questions related to the Riemann's Hypothesis.

Tags: inequality, riemann-hypothesis

Let n be an integer , if n satisfies Robin's Inequality ($\sigma(n)$ /n < $e^{\gamma}$ lnlnn) say n is 'regular'. If n doesn't satisfy Robin's Inequality say n is a 'counter' or a counter-example. One can prove if a and b are coprime and are both counterexamples of Robin's Inequality then so is (a b). Also if m is a regular number where m is not a prime power them m has a proper divisor h such that 1 < h < m , where h is also regular. Let A be the minimum counter that has no proper divisor that is regular; if A has at least two distinct prime divisors p and q so A = (p Q) where q divides Q, this would imply p is a counter but I don't think a single prime is a counterexample to Robin's Inequality. Is it? So A would be a prime power, but similarly a prime power is not a counterexample is this right? These arguments seem to imply every counter example has a proper divisor that is regular.

Comment: If there are any, the first counterexample is superabundant, and  likely also colossally abundant; such numbers are fairly similar, in factorization, to the least common multiple of all consecutive integers from $1$ up to some  $N.$ See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossally_abundant_number

Comment: I noticed if $\psi(n)\$=n/($\theta(n)\$  then ($\psi(n)\$) ($\sigma({n^2}$)/(n^2) > $\{sigma(n)/n}^2\$. If n^2 is regular and n is 'counter' then ($\psi(n)\$) (e^{$\gamma\$}) lnln(n^2) > (e^2{$\gamma\$}) lnln(n)

Comment: I find this inputting system frustating. I noticed if 'psi'(n) = (n/'theta'(n)) then (psi(n))('sigma'(n^2)/n^2) > ('sigma'(n)/n)^2. If n^2 is regular and n is 'counter' then ($\psi(n)$)(e^{gamma}) lnln(n^2) > (e^(2'gamma'))((lnln(n))^2). So ($\psi(n)$)(ln2 +lnln(n)) > e^(gamma) (lnln(n)^2). Therefore ($\psi(n)$) (3/2) > (e^(gamma)) (lnln(n)). So ($\psi(n)$) > (2/3)(e^(gamma))(lnlnn) ; $\psi(n)$ < (3/2)^r where r = $\omega(n)$. Could one use these arguments to prove if sufficiently large n is counter so is n^2?

Comment: If one could prove that if n is 'counter' where $\sigma(n)$)/n >= $e^{\gamma}$ (ln ln(n)) then $n^2$ is counter then could one prove Riemann's Hypothesis?